# Twin square-free numbers of the form $6k-1,6k+1$?

Tags: number-theory, twin-primes

Is it easy to show (or even known) that there are infinitely many square-free pairs $6k-1,6k+1$?

(Presumably, not disproven yet, since a lot of people would be wasting their time on the twin prime conjecture if it was.)

Comment: I have no proof, but there should be infinite many numbers of the form $N=p\#^2$, such that $N-1$ and $N+1$ are both squarefree.

Comment: If we could prove that $6^{2^n}+1$ is always square-free, or something like that, we might have a more constructive proof than the accepted answer, but I haven't found it.

Comment: This is to provide feedback about your question, I don't know if my comment has a good mathematical content and if it is related to your question. I believe that the following conjecture about arithmetic means holds: *The (positive) integers* $6n-1$ *and* $6n+1$ *are twin primes if and only if satisfy* $$1+\frac{\varphi(6n-1)+\varphi(6n+1)}{2}=\frac{\operatorname{rad}(6n-1)+\operatorname{rad}(6n+1)}{2},$$
*where* $\varphi(m)$ *denotes the Euler's totient and* $\operatorname{rad}(m)$ *is the square-free kernel (this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer))*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a prime $p > 3$, the setf $A_p = \{k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\} : 6k \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p^2}\}$ contains exactly two elements in each interval of length $p^2$.

Also, if $n\geq 7$ then $A_p\cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}=\emptyset$ when $p\geq n$, since $p^2\mid 6k\pm 1$ means $6k+1\geq p^2$ which in turn means $k\geq\frac{p^2-1}{6} \geq p+1>n$.

Thus

$$\biggl\lvert\{ 1,\dotsc,n\} \cap \bigcup_{p > 3} A_p\biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{3 < p \leqslant n} 2\biggl\lceil \frac{n}{p^2}\biggr\rceil \leqslant 2\pi(n) + 2n\sum_{3 < p\leqslant n} \frac{1}{p^2},$$

and since $\frac{\pi(n)}{n}\to 0$, the natural density of

$$A = \bigcup_{p > 3} A_p$$

is bounded above by

$$\sum_{ p > 3} \frac{2}{p^2} < 2\sum_{k = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} < 1.$$

Hence the natural density of $B = \mathbb{N}\setminus (A\cup \{0\})$ is positive, in particular $B$ is infinite.

(Corrected argument per [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)' comment.)

Comment: Nice. Will leave open for a bit in case someone comes up with a constructive proof, but wish I could +1 this more times. :)

Comment: Wait, can you actually add natural density like this? It is obvious that natural density of finite sets is zero, but the union of infinitely many finite sets can be all of the natural numbers. I think the key is that these $A_p$ are periodic.

Comment: So $$\left|\{1,2,\dots,n\} \cap \bigcup A_p\right|\leq \sum_{p<n} 2\left\lceil \frac{n}{p^2}\right\rceil \leq 2\pi(n) + \sum \frac{2n}{p^2}$$ And then your argument follows since $\pi(n)/n\to 0$.

Comment: You're right of course, @ThomasAndrews, the periodicity is required for the conclusion. I had the feeling I forgot something, but couldn't lay my hands on it. Turns out I forgot something quite important. _blush_

Comment: I don't see why you decided to call this community Wiki. Yeah, I helped, but it was your basic insight. I just fixed a glitch. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews On the one hand, I'd consider it a major contribution, on the other, CW lowers the bar for others to contribute further improvements. And it's not as if I needed the reputation. Even if I stop being a moderator, I'm still safe in the range of 20k privileges.